# jQuery, select, css

Tags: html, css, jquery

У меня есть текст, и селект с цветами, и я выбрав один из них должен применить его к тексту.
Проблема наверное в скрипте, и получаю цвет который мне нужно, не понимаю как правильно применить его к тексту, возможно в скобках `css()` я не то пишу, подскажет кто то? Заранее спасибо!

```js
$("#jquery-btn1").click(function() {
  $("#jq-select").val();
  $(".tekst").css(val);
})
```

```css
.zielony {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.pomaranczowy {
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}

.rozowy {
  background-color: lightpink;
}

.niebieski {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}

.fioletowy {
  background-color: rgb(140, 99, 185);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="tekst">Текст</p>
<select class="jquery-btn" id="jq-select">
  <option>zielony</option>
  <option>pomaranczowy</option>
  <option>rozowy</option>
  <option>niebieski</option>
  <option>fioletowy</option>
  <button class="jquery-btn" id="jquery-btn1">Zmień tło</button>
  <button class="jquery-btn" id="jquery-btn2">Zmień czcionkę</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$("#jquery-btn1").click(function() {
  $(".tekst").attr("class", "tekst " + $("#jq-select").val());
})
```

```css
.zielony {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.pomaranczowy {
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}

.rozowy {
  background-color: lightpink;
}

.niebieski {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}

.fioletowy {
  background-color: rgb(140, 99, 185);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="tekst">Текст</p>
<select class="jquery-btn" id="jq-select">
  <option>zielony</option>
  <option>pomaranczowy</option>
  <option>rozowy</option>
  <option>niebieski</option>
  <option>fioletowy</option>
</select>
<button class="jquery-btn" id="jquery-btn1">Zmień tło</button>
<button class="jquery-btn" id="jquery-btn2">Zmień czcionkę</button>
```

Comment: Опередили... :)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 Пардон.

Comment: А например без 'attr' это здесь не сделать?

Comment: @Влад Не темните. Скажите честно, что Вас не устраивает в `attr`.

Comment: А нет, уже разобрался, спасибо!

Comment: Кстати, "tekst " и "tekst" - это разное, не знал