# jQuery, select один на две кнопки

Tags: html, css, jquery

Я хочу из одного селекта, и когда у меня есть две кнопки, то по первой изменить backround-color, а по второй просто color. Например у меня есть стили:

```css
.zielony {
    background-color: rgb(179, 247, 179) ;
    color: green;
}

.pomaranczowy {
    background-color: rgb(255, 197, 174);
    color: rgb(146, 95, 0);
}

.rozowy {
    background-color: rgb(250, 195, 204);
    color: palevioletred;
}

.niebieski {
    background-color: rgb(157, 215, 252);
    color: blue;
}

.fioletowy {
    background-color: rgb(188, 144, 235);
    color: purple;
}
```

```html
<p class="tekst>Tekst</p>
<select class="jquery-btn" id="jq-select">
    <option>zielony</option>
    <option>pomaranczowy</option>
    <option>rozowy</option>
    <option>niebieski</option>
    <option>fioletowy</option>
</select>
<button class="jquery-btn" id="jquery-btn1">Zmień tło</button>
<button class="jquery-btn" id="jquery-btn2">Zmień czcionkę</button>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#jquery-btn1").click(function(){
        $(".tekst").attr("class", "tekst " + $("#jq-select").val());
    })
    $("#jquery-btn2").click(function(){
        $(".tekst").attr("class", "tekst " + $("#jq-select").val());
    })
});
```

То-есть мне в любом случае нужно создать еще раз те же классы но только со свойством color, или как? Просто я хочу что бы у меня был только один селект и название у его выборов тоже одно, а классы нужно разные создавать, как тогда быть? Просто сейчас у меня по первой и второй кнопке меняется и фон с шрифт, и это логично. Заранее спасибо!

Я пробовал так, чтоб добавлять через css() только нужное мне свойство и получается следующие, но все же не работает:

```js
$("#jquery-btn1").click(function(){
    $(".tekst").css('background-color').attr("class", "tekst " + $("#jq-select").val());
})
$("#jquery-btn2").click(function(){
    $(".tekst").css('color').attr("class", "tekst " + $("#jq-select").val());
})
```

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы совать `.css` куда попало, лучше прочитайте про него [подробнее](https://api.jquery.com/css/).

Comment: И ещё, Вам ответили на [предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1267467/221218)

Comment: Ок, больше не буду совать ничего и никуда :( Спасибо.

Comment: просто почитайте об этом методе, он работает явно не так как вы написали.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы использовал следующий вариант

```js
let el = $('.tekst');

$("#jquery-btn1").click(function(){
  let val = $('#jq-select option:selected').attr('data-background-color');
  el.css('background-color', val);
});

$("#jquery-btn2").click(function(){
  let val = $('#jq-select option:selected').attr('data-color');
  el.css('color', val);
});
```

```css
.zielony {
    background-color: rgb(179, 247, 179) ;
    color: green;
}

.pomaranczowy {
    background-color: rgb(255, 197, 174);
    color: rgb(146, 95, 0);
}

.rozowy {
    background-color: rgb(250, 195, 204);
    color: palevioletred;
}

.niebieski {
    background-color: rgb(157, 215, 252);
    color: blue;
}

.fioletowy {
    background-color: rgb(188, 144, 235);
    color: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="tekst">Tekst</p>
<select class="jquery-btn" id="jq-select">
    <option data-background-color="rgb(179, 247, 179)" data-color="green">zielony</option>
    <option data-background-color="rgb(255, 197, 174)" data-color="rgb(146, 95, 0)">pomaranczowy</option>
    <option data-background-color="rgb(250, 195, 204)" data-color="palevioletred">rozowy</option>
    <option data-background-color="rgb(157, 215, 252)" data-color="green">niebieski</option>
    <option data-background-color="rgb(188, 144, 235)" data-color="purple">fioletowy</option>
</select>
<button class="jquery-btn" id="jquery-btn1">Zmień tło</button>
<button class="jquery-btn" id="jquery-btn2">Zmień czcionkę</button>
```

---

И у Вас снова ошибка в коде: пропущен закрывающий символ значения атрибута

```
<!--           ⇓      -->
<p class="tekst>Tekst</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

Предложу ещё один вариант, в котором CSS-стили отличаются суффиксом для текста и фона:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    let toggleCssClassBySuffix = function(selector, suffix, className) {
      $(selector).each(function(idx, itm) {
        let classes = itm.className
                      .split(" ")
                      .filter(cls => !cls.endsWith(suffix));
        classes.push(className + suffix);
        itm.className = classes.join(" ");
      });
    };
    $("#change-bg").click(function() {
        toggleCssClassBySuffix(".tekst", "-bg", $("#colors").val());
    })
    $("#change-font-color").click(function(){
        toggleCssClassBySuffix(".tekst", "-font", $("#colors").val());
    })
});
```

```css
.zielony-bg { background-color: rgb(179, 247, 179); }
.zielony-font { color: green; }

.pomaranczowy-bg { background-color: rgb(255, 197, 174); }
.pomaranczowy-font { color: rgb(146, 95, 0); }

.rozowy-bg { background-color: rgb(250, 195, 204); }
.rozowy-font { color: palevioletred; }

.niebieski-bg { background-color: rgb(157, 215, 252); }
.niebieski-font { color: blue; }

.fioletowy-bg { background-color: rgb(188, 144, 235); }
.fioletowy-font { color: purple; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="tekst">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
<p class="tekst">Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
<select id="colors">
    <option>zielony</option>
    <option>pomaranczowy</option>
    <option>rozowy</option>
    <option>niebieski</option>
    <option>fioletowy</option>
</select>
<button id="change-bg">Change BG</button>
<button id="change-font-color">Change font color</button>
```

Comment: Хороший вариант) (+)