# jQuery, снова проблемы с селектом

Tags: html, css, jquery

У меня есть вариант смены фона текста по одной кнопке и смены цвета шрифта - по другой. Но вот в чем проблема - я могу только раз поставить нужный мне класс и позже, когда я еще раз меняю цвета, то предыдущие классы не удаляются, и получается так что я могу только один раз использовать один цвет, так как класс не удаляется при добавлении следующего. Можно ли это как то исправить?

```html
<p class="tekst">qwerty</p>
<p class="tekst">qwerty</p>
<p class="tekst">qwerty</p>

<select id="jq-select">
  <option value="niebieski">Niebieski</option>
  <option value="czerwony">Czerwony</option>
  <option value="zolty">Żółty</option>
  <option value="pomaranczowy">Pomarańczowy</option>
  <option value="zielony">Zielony</option>
</select>
<button id="jquery-btn1">Zmień tło</button>
<button id="jquery-btn2">Zmień czcionkę</button>

<style type="text/css">
.niebieski-background {
  background-color: var(--data-background-color-blue);
}
.czerwony-background {
  background-color: var(--data-background-color-red);
}
.zolty-background {
  background-color: var(--data-background-color-yellow);
}
.pomaranczowy-background {
  background-color: var(--data-background-color-orange);
}
.zielony-background {
  background-color: var(--data-background-color-green);
}
.niebieski-color {
  color: var(--data-color-blue);
}
.czerwony-color {
  color: var(--data-color-red);
}
.zolty-color {
  color: var(--data-color-yellow);
}
.pomaranczowy-color {
  color: var(--data-color-orange);
}
.zielony-color {
  color: var(--data-color-green);
}
</style> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#jquery-btn1").click(function() {
  var val = $("#jq-select").val();
  $(".tekst").addClass(val + "-background");
});
$("#jquery-btn2").click(function() {
  var val = $("#jq-select").val();
  $(".tekst").addClass(val + "-color")
});
</script>
```

Comment: А чем Вас не устроил мой прежний ответ? Вы по сути задаёте опять тот-же вопрос, на который Вам дали ответ.

Comment: Здесь с использованием классов в файле.css, да и проблема уже в другом, сверху написал

Comment: Проблема у Вас всё та-же. Предложенный мною ранее вариант рабочий и полностью и даже более, решает Вашу задачу. P.S.: а меня искренне удивляют Ваши  одинаковые по сути вопросы :) В чём проблема?

Comment: Здесь с использованием классов в файле.css

Comment: Где находятся классы CSS без разницы. В [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1267526/182750) решении что Вас не устраивает? Что-то не работает? Что-то не получается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавлю еще один ответ. Я бы все переписал вот так вот:

```js
$(".js-btn-1").on('click', function() {
    $(".text").css('background-color', $(".js-select").val());
});
$(".js-btn-2").on('click', function() {
    $(".text").css('color', $(".js-select").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="text">qwerty</p>
<p class="text">qwerty</p>
<p class="text">qwerty</p>
<select class="js-select">
  <option value="#4169E1">Blue</option>
  <option value="#FF4500">Red</option>
  <option value="#FFFF00">Yellow</option>
  <option value="#FF7F50">Orange</option>
  <option value="#7CFC00">Green</option>
</select>
<button class="js-btn-1">background</button>
<button class="js-btn-2">color</button>
```

Comment: Вот это уже почти то что нужно, спасибо и на этом!

Answer (score 1):

Сначала чистите все классы, потом делаете то, что делали.

```js
$("#jquery-btn1").click(function() {
    var val = $("#jq-select").val();
    $(".tekst").attr('class', function(_, old){
        return $.grep(old.split(/ +/), function(v){
             return !v.match(/-background$/);
        }).join(' ');
    });
    $(".tekst").addClass(val + "-background")
});
$("#jquery-btn2").click(function() {
    var val = $("#jq-select").val();
     $(".tekst").attr('class', function(_, old){
        return $.grep(old.split(/ +/), function(v){
             return !v.match(/-color$/);
        }).join(' ');
    });
    $(".tekst").addClass(val + "-color")
});
```

```css
.niebieski-background {
    background-color: blue;
}

.czerwony-background {
    background-color: red;
}

.zolty-background {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.pomaranczowy-background {
    background-color: orange;
}

.zielony-background {
    background-color: green;
}
/* ------------------------------------------------ */
.niebieski-color {
    color: blue;
}

.czerwony-color {
    color: red;
}

.zolty-color {
    color: yellow;
}

.pomaranczowy-color {
    color: orange;
}

.zielony-color {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="tekst">qwerty</p>
<p class="tekst">qwerty</p>
<p class="tekst">qwerty</p>
<select class="jquery-btn buttonmoon jquery-btn-left" id="jq-select">
  <option value="niebieski">Niebieski</option>
  <option value="czerwony">Czerwony</option>
  <option value="zolty">Żółty</option>
  <option value="pomaranczowy">Pomarańczowy</option>
  <option value="zielony">Zielony</option>
</select>
<button class="jquery-btn buttonmoon" id="jquery-btn1">Zmień tło</button>
<button class="jquery-btn buttonmoon" id="jquery-btn2">Zmień czcionkę</button>
```

Comment: Почему то сейчас когда поставил бекраунд то когда стилизую шрифт, то бекраунд пропадает и наоборот, а должно быть и то и то

Comment: @Влад отредактировал.

Comment: Это не подходит, так как очень сложный код, можно намного проще сделать

Comment: Сделайте :) Откланиваюсь.

Comment: @Влад намного проще - это напрямую цвет элементу задавать, без класса.