# jQuery. не работает селект выбор

Tags: html, jquery

У меня есть текст, выбор, и две кнопки. Нажимая первую я хочу менять цвет фона у текста, а по
второй - его цвет, и не понимаю почему мой скрипт не работает, буду благодарен за подсказки, спасибо!

```
css ↓

.niebieski {
    background-color: var(--data-background-color-blue);
    color: var(--data-color-blue);
}

.czerwony {
    background-color: var(--data-background-color-red);
    color: var(--data-color-red);
}

.zolty {
    background-color: var(--data-background-color-yellow);
    color: var(--data-color-yellow);
}

.pomaranczowy {
    background-color: var(--data-background-color-orange);
    color: var(--data-color-orange);
}

.zielony {
    background-color: var(--data-background-color-green);
    color: var(--data-color-green);
}

html ↓
<h2>Zmiana koloru tekstu i tła</h2>
                    <p class="tekst">Tekst
                    </p>
                    <p class="tekst">Tekst
                    </p>
                    <p class="tekst">Tekst</p>
                <select class="jquery-btn buttonmoon jquery-btn-left" id="jq-select">
                    <option value="niebieski">Niebieski</option>
                    <option value="czerwony">Czerwony</option>
                    <option value="zolty">Żółty</option>
                    <option value="pomaranczowy">Pomarańczowy</option>
                    <option value="zielony">Zielony</option>
            <button class="jquery-btn buttonmoon" id="jquery-btn1">Zmień tło</button>
            <button class="jquery-btn buttonmoon" id="jquery-btn2">Zmień czcionkę</button>

script ↓


    $("#jquery-btn1").click(function() {
        var val = $("#jq-select").val();
        $(".tekst").css('background-color', val)
    });
    $("#jquery-btn2").click(function() {
        var val = $("#jq-select").val();
        $(".tekst").css('color', val)
    });
```

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? -  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1267465/jquery-select-css

Comment: Что-то я не вижу ни одной кнопки в html.

Comment: Это другое, и здесь можно по проще сделать, только я не могу понять в чем проблема на данном этапе

Comment: Добавил кнопку, не дописал просто

Comment: Слева от ответа - знак "галочка".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#jquery-btn1").click(function() {
  var val = $("#jq-select").val();
  $(".tekst").addClass(val + "-background")
});
$("#jquery-btn2").click(function() {
  var val = $("#jq-select").val();
  $(".tekst").addClass(val + "-color")
});
```

```css
.zolty-background {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.zolty-color {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Zmiana koloru tekstu i tła</h2>
<p class="tekst">Tekst
</p>
<p class="tekst">Tekst
</p>
<p class="tekst">Tekst</p>
<select class="jquery-btn buttonmoon jquery-btn-left" id="jq-select">
  <option value="zolty">Żółty</option>
</select>
<button class="jquery-btn buttonmoon" id="jquery-btn1">Zmień tło</button>
<button class="jquery-btn buttonmoon" id="jquery-btn2">Zmień czcionkę</button>
```

Comment: А с одним классом никак этого не сделать получается?

Comment: @Влад Может Вам все-таки почитать, что делает функция `css`?

Comment: Может и так, спасибо все же